# Use jQuery scroll plugin to avoid # on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I want to use scroll jQuery plugin to scroll to `anchor tag` because I don't want to browser to add # to the end of url when you click links.
I don't want anyone to bookmark url of my web site with #.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a name="top"></a>TOP
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <a href="#top">top</top>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is `jQuery.ScrollTo` the most standard plugin to do that?
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

I want to support IE6, FF4, Chrome, Android, and iphone.
Does jQuery.ScrollTo support them?
Or shouldn't I use the scroll plugin if I need browser comatibility?

Comment: Post your code. In general, you simply need to add "return false;" to a function to remove the url hash.

Comment: Just a sidenote, IE6 is dead as Microsoft finally is forcing users to upgrade til IE7>

Comment: @js_ I mean the jquery functions.

Comment: @Scott I don't have jQuery functions. I'm using just html. 
And that's why `#top` is added to url when you click `<a href="#top">top</top>`.
I think jQuery.ScrollTo will solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry thought you were using ScrollTo.. I misread.... themerlinproject has an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin + give your users a nice smooth scroll with scrollTop (live example here - http://jsfiddle.net/7qr3y/9/ ):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="bottomscroll">bottom</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.bottomscroll').click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#bottom').offset().top }, 'slow');
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. That's nice. '#bottom' is `<div id="bottom">` or `<a name="bottom">`? Does your code can support IE6 and Android?

Comment: 1) any element with id="bottom" 2) android is good, IE6... not sure. If you have IE6 pull up the jsfiddle I created above to test it. I don't have IE6

Comment: I've tested. Your fiddle also worked in IE6 and FF2. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. If this solved your answer please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a newer version of jQuery.. then `preventDefault` may be better.

```
<a name="top"></a>

$(".top").on('click', function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#container').offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Why `preventDefault` is better than `return false`? Does your code support IE6 and Android?