# Back to top link on mobile site doesn't work on android

Tags: jquery, android, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have an interesting question. I'm building a web site geared towards mobile devices (please not this is not a question regarding mobile web apps, it's a plain HTML / CSS / javascript website).
We need to implement a "Back to top" link in the footer of all pages, so it's easier to navigate back to the top on devices with small screens.

I'll show the code now, just wanted to mention this works perfectly on iphone/ipod touch devices, and even my FF, safari and chrome desktop browsers. But on android it just doesn't want to work.

Steps to reproduce the error on my android device:
- Scroll down to the bottom of the page.
- Click on the back to top link. 
-- The page scrolls up nicely but then flickers and scrolls back down to the bottom of the page again.

It almost looks like the scrolling event doesn't stop in the background, and once the scrollto function is done, it resumes the scrolling to bottom again. My code is supposed to kill any current running animations, which I was hoping should fix this. But it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.linktop').click(function() {
    $('body,html').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    },
    250);
    return false;
  });
 });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
```

for a jQuery Mobile back to top plugin and it worked on Android without the problems you've had.

Check out the code here http://operationmobile.com/jquery-mobile-ux-add-a-back-to-top-button/

Answer (score 1):

I tried lots of different solutions including the one suggested above, which is elegant except does not work on gingerbread and requires jQ mobile.

The following code works on iPhone, Android 2.2+ including gingerbread as well as regular browsers and it only requires regular jQ.  I found the code at this link  [Use jQuery scroll plugin to avoid # on url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559565/use-jquery-scroll-plugin-to-avoid-on-url)
and modified for the example below, which I tested on iPhone 4s, Galaxy II and an older Android device.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js'></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    $('.2top').click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#top').offset().top }, 'slow');
        return false;
            });
    });//]]>  

  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="top">go to the  bottom of this page</div>

  <p style="height:2200px">dddddd...</p>

  <a href="#" class="2top">back to top</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had this same problem with 2.3.6. One thing I had to add to your click listener is "(this).blur();" right before animate is called for this to work. This way, after the user is scrolled to the top of the div, the browser doesn't immediately jump down to the ".2top" button since it is currently focused.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with the "back to top" buttons, and after trying some jquery alternatives I've found this simple html option for "old browsers" but it's working on mobile devices too. Seems that we forgot the old reason why `#top` works:

```
<body>
    <a id="top"></a>  
    <!-- content goes here -->
    <a href="#top">Back to top</a>
</body>
```

and an alternative is using an existing id:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- content goes here -->
    <a href="#wrapper">back to top</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

source:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/11/short-story-about-top-links/